# Gather values from different tables based on a table field

Tags: mysql

**Suppose I have the following table structure:**

- ***TABLE 1***

main_id | type | information

```
first segway excellent
second car   mercedes
third  bike  sliceofwind
```

- ***TABLE segway***

id | grade

```
1  excellent
2  bad
3 (...)
```

- ***TABLE car***

id | brand

```
1  mercedes
2  honda
3  (...)
```

- ***TABLE bike***

id | tires

```
1 sliceofwind
2 flatasfaque
3 (...)
```

What I'd like to do is dinamically obtain information from different tables based on **type from table1**.

Here's the generic example of a query that I've tried

```
SELECT (CASE 
WHEN table1.type = 'segway' AND segway.grade = table1.information 
     THEN segway.id,
WHEN table1.type = 'car' AND car.brand = table1.information 
     THEN car.id,
WHEN table1.type = 'bike' AND bike.tires = table1.information 
     THEN bike.id 
        END) AS information 
FROM table1,segway,bike,car WHERE table1.main_id IN ("ids")
```

The result of this query is a cartesian product because all the data from all tables will be retrieved despite the restrictions inside the case because not all tables have restrictions.
I'd like to know if there is a way to work around this without changing the table structure, and if not plea for some hints! (I'm up to some kinky sql stuff, what I'm asking here if **it is indeed possible** to do this, despite it being advised or not and why!).

Comment: Have u tried distinct select?

Comment: You can do so [*demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f1aaa/12)

Answer (score 1):

This might be one way to do it.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN segway s 
  on T1.main_id = s.id and T1.type= 'segway'
LEFT JOIN car c 
  on T1.main_id = c.id and T1.type= 'car'
LEFT JOIN bike b
  on T1.main_id = b.id and T1.type= 'bike'
WHERE t1.main_ID in (SomeList)
```

segway, car, and bike table columns will be null when the Table1's type doesn't match.
However this seems like it would give you back more data/columns than you need.  I think you'd be better off writing separate queries outside the database and call them depending on the value they select.  OR using a procedure within the database and conditional logic to return the desired result set.  (again 3 separate queries and conditional logic in the database)  but without understanding use case, I can't really say which would be better.

We could further coalese the brand, tires and grade into a "Value" field as in

`Select t1.*, coalese(s.grade,c.brand,b.tires) as value` but I'm not sure this offers any help either.

if we needed to only return table 1 values and set values from the other tables... you said kinky, not me.

I can't see how the Cartesian would occur this way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your expected result, try this query..

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN s.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN s.`id` 
 WHEN c.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN c.`id` 
 WHEN b.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN b.`id` 
END) AS information FROM table1 AS t1
 LEFT JOIN segway s ON t1.type= 'segway'
 LEFT JOIN car c ON t1.type= 'car'
 LEFT JOIN bike b ON t1.type= 'bike' 
WHERE t1.main_ID IN (1, 2, 3) AND (t1.information = s.`grade` OR 
                                   t1.`information`=c.brand OR 
                                   t1.`information`=b.tires);
```